# Spark: how to use SparkContext.textFile for local file system

Tags: apache-spark

I'm just getting started using Apache Spark (in Scala, but the language is irrelevant).  I'm using **standalone mode** and I'll want to process a text file from a **local file system** (so nothing distributed like HDFS).

According to the documentation of the `textFile` method from `SparkContext`, it will

> Read a text file from HDFS, a local file system (available on all
>   nodes), or any Hadoop-supported file system URI, and return it as an
>   RDD of Strings.

What is unclear for me is if the whole text file can just be copied to all the nodes, or if the input data should already be partitioned, e.g. if using 4 nodes and a csv file with 1000 lines, have 250 lines on each node.

I suspect each node should have the whole file but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Each node should contain a whole file. In this case local file system will be logically indistinguishable from the HDFS, in respect to this file.

Comment: No reference given, but assuming this is correct because of your repuation and expierence.  Thanks!

Comment: Thank you! It is what I think, but I am quite sure in this case. Anyway - please let me know if you have some problems with it.

Comment: From [the programming guide on external datasets](http://spark.apache.org/docs/1.2.1/programming-guide.html#external-datasets):
_If using a path on the local filesystem, the file must also be accessible at the same path on worker nodes. Either copy the file to all workers or use a network-mounted shared file system._

Comment: In this case, how would Spark parallel processing the file?For example, if there are 4 worker node in the spark cluster, and you copy a copy of the entire file to the same folder on each worker node. Will spark read the file 4 times(once on each worker) or just random pick one file from the 4 worker nodes?

Comment: @DavidGruzman Is there *any* way via spark to distribute the data to the nodes over the wire? (running on k8s) Seems crazy to have to read the file N times?

Comment: getSplits() ..?

Answer (score 4):

prepend `file://` to your local file path

Comment: Didn't work in my case. However, it worked with just one slash:
`sc.textFile('file:/home/data/lines').count()`

Answer (score 2):

From Spark's FAQ page - 
If you don't use Hadoop/HDFS, "if you run on a cluster, you will need some form of shared file system (for example, NFS mounted at the same path on each node). If you have this type of filesystem, you can just deploy Spark in standalone mode."

https://spark.apache.org/faq.html

Answer (score 2):

Proper way of using is with three slashes. Two for syntax (just like http://) and one for mount point of linux file system e.g., sc.textFile(file:///home/worker/data/my_file.txt). If you are using local mode then only file is sufficient. In case of standalone cluster, the file must be copied at each node. Note that the contents of the file must be exactly same, otherwise spark returns funny results.

Answer (score 1):

**Spark-1.6.1**

**Java-1.7.0_99**

**Nodes in cluster-3(HDP).**

`Case 1:`

```
Running in local mode local[n]
```

`file:///..` and `file:/..` reads file from local system

`Case 2:`

```
`--master yarn-cluster`
```

`Input path does not exist: for file:/ and file://`

And for `file://`

`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException :Wrong FS: file://.. expected: file:///`

Answer (score 1):

Add "file:///" uri in place of "file://". This solved the issue for me.