# Spark read local file need the file exists in the master node

Tags: apache-spark

1.My problem.

I run a wordCount program in a 4-nodes spark cluster. The input of the program is local file system file. I know i should distribute the file to all worker nodes(in my situation, quad102 is master, quad103-quad105 are slaves, so the file should exist in the same path in these slaves nodes, and i'm sure i do not make the quad102 as slave) according this problem's answer [Spark: how to use SparkContext.textFile for local file system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24735516/spark-how-to-use-sparkcontext-textfile-for-local-file-system)
**!!!*But,in my practice***, if the master node doesn't have the same file, the program can't run too, and in fact, the 4-nodes all need have this file in the same file,otherwise it can't run. I had read through the SparkContext.textFile source code, i don't find any problems, **could someone explain why the master need this file too?(In my opinion, only slave nodes need this file.)**

2.My program and cluster configuration.

(1)4-nodes cluster is standalone mode, quad102 is master, quad103-quad105 are slaves.

(2)the program is very simple:

```
object WordCount {
  def main(args:Array[String]) {
    //For test
    if(args.length == 1) println(args(0))

    val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("WordCount")
    val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
    val rdd = sc.textFile(args(0))
    rdd.flatMap(p => p.split("\\s+")).map(x => (x, 1)).reduceByKey(_ +   _).collect().foreach(println(_))
    sc.stop()
  }
}
```

(3)The command i run this program.

```
spark-submit --master spark://192.168.1.2:7077 --class cn.siat.postspark.mllib.WordCount file:///root/postspark_2.10-1.0.jar file:///root/Documents/java-listen-data/data/test1
```

Answer (score 1):

I can explain this problem now.
Because i run this program in the master node. So the file should exist in the master node, if i run this program in the slave node, everything is ok.
I have do some test to verify my guess. You should make sure the file exists on the node which you run the program, this file just used for getSplits by the FileInputFormat , the content in the file is not read, at last, the worker node task will read the file in the localhost according to the split.

Comment: Isn't it actually the machine where the spark-application is running (and not the spark-master node) on which the file needs to be accessible in order to determine splits?