# Apache Spark to transfer data

Tags: java, apache-spark

I setup Apache Spark on a server, it is now all operational and waiting for data to crunch.

Here is my Java code:

```
    SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("myFirstJob").setMaster("spark://10.0.100.120:7077");
    JavaSparkContext javaSparkContext = new JavaSparkContext(conf);
    javaSparkContext.setLogLevel("WARN");
    SQLContext sqlContext = new SQLContext(javaSparkContext);

    System.out.println("Hello, Remote Spark v." + javaSparkContext.version());

    DataFrame df;
    df = sqlContext.read().option("dateFormat", "yyyy-mm-dd")
            .json("./src/main/resources/north-carolina-school-performance-data.json"); // this is line #31
    df = df.withColumn("district", df.col("fields.district"));
    df = df.groupBy("district").count().orderBy(df.col("district"));
    df.show(150);
```

Spark complains that the `./src/main/resources/north-carolina-school-performance-data.json` file is not on the server:

```
16/07/12 15:08:31 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 1.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 1, micha): java.io.FileNotFoundException: File file:/Users/jgp/git/net.jgp.labs.spark/src/main/resources/north-carolina-school-performance-data.json does not exist
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.deprecatedGetFileStatus(RawLocalFileSystem.java:534)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.getFileLinkStatusInternal(RawLocalFileSystem.java:747)
...
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:109)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.json(DataFrameReader.scala:244)
    **at net.jgp.labs.spark.FirstJob.main(FirstJob.java:31)**
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: File file:/Users/jgp/git/net.jgp.labs.spark/src/main/resources/north-carolina-school-performance-data.json does not exist
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.deprecatedGetFileStatus(RawLocalFileSystem.java:534)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.getFileLinkStatusInternal(RawLocalFileSystem.java:747)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.getFileStatus(RawLocalFileSystem.java:524)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FilterFileSystem.getFileStatus(FilterFileSystem.java:409)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem$ChecksumFSInputChecker.<init>(ChecksumFileSystem.java:140)
```

Fair enough, it is *not* on the server. I was hoping that open would take the file locally, where the driver is running and send it over. Is there a way to do it or is it outside the scope of Apache Spark? If it is outside, any recommendation on doing it properly (I mean I can set up a CIFS server, etc. but I find it a little ugly)?

Comment: Use distributed file system of your choice or any other data sources that can be accessed from all nodes. Passing data from driver is possible but works only in one way and rarely scales to any real applications.

Comment: Have you tried putting json("file://...")? But have a read of this section http://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.0/programming-guide.html#external-datasets File should be accessible on worker nodes on the same path..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spark: how to use SparkContext.textFile for local file system](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24735516/spark-how-to-use-sparkcontext-textfile-for-local-file-system)

Comment: @Serhiy: file:// does not do it, and it is a similar post...

Comment: @zero323: Thanks, I guess I was hoping for it to magically appear on all nodes... Oh well... This is why we have SANs I guess.