# Deleting a csv file which is created using numpy.savetxt in pyspark

Tags: python, numpy, pyspark

I am new to pyspark and python.
After saving a file in local system using `numpy.savetxt("test.csv",file,delimiter=',')`
I am using **os** to delete that file. `os.remove("test.csv")`. I am getting an error **java.io.FileNotFoundException File file:/someDir/test.csv does not exist**. The file `numpy.savetxt()` creates file with only read permission. How can save the same with read and write permission. 
Using spark version 2.1

Comment: spark probably has nothing to do here since you are using numpy's apis to save file locally. Have you manually checked whether after `numpy.savetxt`, file really exists on local system or not?

Comment: Yes it do exists on the local system. And one more thing which I observed recently that I can't able to read that csv file from pyspark shell.

Comment: to read from local file system, you will have to give full address like - `filerdd=sc.textFile("file:///path/to/file.txt")`

Comment: I tried the same, but I am getting File not found exception from pyspark shell. 
**This is the stack trace**
File "/apps/spark-2.1.0/python/lib/py4j-0.10.4-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 319, in get_return_value py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o36.load. : org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 0.0 (TID 3, 30.0.0.167, executor 0):

Comment: java.io.FileNotFoundException: File file:/opt/center.csv does not exist at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.deprecatedGetFileStatus(RawLocalFileSystem.java:611)

I am using spark 2.1 version with python 3.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your spark workers are not able to access the file. You are probably running the master and workers on different servers. When you are trying to work on files, while having setup workers across different machines make sure these workers can access the file.You could keep the same copy of files among all the workers in the exact same location. It is always advisable to use DFS like Hadoop like "hdfs://path/file". When you do the workers can access these files. 
More details on:
[Spark: how to use SparkContext.textFile for local file system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24735516/spark-how-to-use-sparkcontext-textfile-for-local-file-system)