# Why is Spark trying to load CSV on worker node in standalone mode?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I am currently working with Apache Spark in standalone mode, where I have configured a single worker node. I have a simple code snippet that I would like to execute, and I've provided it below.

```py
from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
sc = SparkSession.builder.appName("YourAppName").getOrCreate()

csvFile = 'file:///home/bennison/Documents/yavar-learnings/spark/pyspark/departuredelays.csv'
file_path_on_master = csvFile
# spark.addFile(csvFile)

data_rdd = sc.read.format('csv').option(
    'inferSchema', 'true').option('header', 'true').load(csvFile)
    
    
data_rdd.show()
data_rdd.createOrReplaceTempView('us_delay_flights_tbl')

# find all flights whose distance is greater than 1,000 miles:
sc.sql('SELECT * FROM us_delay_flights_tbl WHERE distance > 1000 ORDER BY distance DESC').show()

# find all flights between San Francisco (SFO) and Chicago (ORD) with at least a two-hour delay
sc.sql('SELECT date, distance, origin, destination FROM us_delay_flights_tbl WHERE origin = "SFO" AND destination = "ORD" AND delay >= 120 ORDER BY delay DESC').show()

# label all US flights, regardless of origin and destination,with an indication of the delays they experienced: Very Long Delays (> 6 hours), Long Delays (2–6 hours), etc. We’ll add these human-readable labels in a new column called Flight_Delays
sc.sql(
    'SELECT date, distance, origin, destination, CASE WHEN delay = 0 THEN "No Dely" WHEN delay > 0 AND delay < 2 THEN "Tolerable Delays" WHEN delay > 2 AND delay < 6 THEN "Long Delays" WHEN delay > 6 THEN "Very Long Delays" ELSE "Early" END AS delay_def FROM us_delay_flights_tbl ORDER BY delay DESC').show()

(data_rdd.select("distance", "origin", "destination").where(
    'distance > 1000').orderBy(desc('distance'))).show()

(data_rdd.select('date', 'distance', 'origin', 'destination').filter((col('origin') == "SFO")
 & (col("destination") == "ORD") & (col("delay") >= 120)).orderBy(desc('delay')).show())

(data_rdd.select('date', 'distance', 'origin', 'destination', when(col('delay') == 0, 'No Delay').when((col('delay') > 0) & (col('delay') < 2),
 "Tolerable Delays").when((col('delay') > 2) & (col('delay') < 6), "Long Delays").when((col('delay') > 6), "Very Long Delay").otherwise('Early').alias('delay_def')).orderBy(desc(col='delay')).show())

sc.stop()
```

To submit the job, I initiated the Spark master and then the worker node. However, I encountered an issue when attempting to execute the code using the spark-submit command. It appears that Spark is trying to read the CSV file on the worker node, even though the file is located on the master node.

My understanding of Spark's behavior is that the master program should read the CSV file from its own file path and then distribute the data across the cluster as needed. Given this understanding, I'm confused, as to why I'm encountering the error message: "<filename> does not exist."

I've provided the exact error below.

```
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: 
File file:/home/bennison/Documents/yavar-learnings/spark/pyspark/departuredelays.csv does not exist

It is possible the underlying files have been updated. You can explicitly invalidate
the cache in Spark by running 'REFRESH TABLE tableName' command in SQL or by
recreating the Dataset/DataFrame involved.
```

I verified the file's location in the master node, and it does exist at the specified file path.

Could someone please clarify why Spark is attempting to load the CSV file on the worker node rather than the master node, and how I can resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/24736077/8726538 for reference

> From the programming guide on external datasets: If using a path on
> the local filesystem, the file must also be accessible at the same
> path on worker nodes. Either copy the file to all workers or use a
> network-mounted shared file system.

Comment: In which data source does it distribute the data across the clusters?